# In a tree, if a root has a single branch, is it a leaf (terminal vertex) or internal (branch) vertex?

Tags: graph-theory

In a tree, if a root has a single branch (that is, one edge from it to one other vertex), is the root a leaf (terminal vertex) or is the root an internal (branch) vertex?

Another question: a single isolated vertex is or is not a tree? I thought it was, but then realized that a single vertex can be considered a trivial circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a leaf of a rooted is defined as a node with no children, so in the first case, the root is an internal node.

A graph with a single vertex is a tree.  If you consider a single vertex as a cycle, then there are no trees at all.

In the case of a rooted tree consisting of a single vertex, I would say the root is also a leaf.

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on your definition of tree, and is just a matter of convention that should not really be of any importance.

- If you consider that a rooted tree is a graph with no cycle, and a leaf is any vertex with only one adjacent edge, then yes, sure the root is a leaf
- If you consider a more inductive definition of rooted trees, saying that a tree is either a leaf, or it is a list of trees (computer sciency way of seeing things), then no, the root should definitely not be a leaf

I am sure there are plenty of other definitions of trees, that one could use to argue in one direction or another, what matters is when you talk about it, just make sure what setting you are using